# multiple variable ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax

Plain and simple, this is what I am trying to create:

```
function addComment($post_id, $user_id, $comment) {
    var post_id = $post_id;
    var user_id = $user_id;
    var comment = $comment;

    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else xhr = new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    var url = 'commentcreate.php?post_id=' + post_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&comment=' + comment
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
            div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;           
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
    return false;
```

And then I got the PHP file which would be recieving these variables:

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && isset($_GET['user_id']) && isset($_GET['comment'])) $post_id = $_GET['post_id'] && $user_id = $_GET['user_id'] && $comment = $_GET['comment'];
```

Which is code that is extremely hard to read that is *meant* as working like the following:

```
if (
    isset($_GET['post_id'])
    && isset($_GET['user_id'])
    && isset($_GET['comment'])
) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $comment = $_GET['comment'];
}
```

So basicly, I want a function that takes 3 variables, and sends them over to a php file where I can do my thing and add them to the database (to create a comment). But this does not work. It works with 1 variable, but I dont know how to get it to work with more then 1. Im guessing that its something wrong on the php side, but i could be wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't use `&&` when assigning the value to variable

Comment: (@user3091574: well you can, but it's perhaps not expected what happens.)

Comment: @user3383540: You made a simple mistake writing code, perhaps motivated by wanting to put everything in as little lines as necessary. Instead make use of parenthesis and indent your code. Making such mistakes does not qualify as programming question here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: hmm! but it has no meaning then why use it.

Comment: @hakre you just edited the question so that it now actually contains the correct answer and no longer shows the original problem, why would you do that?

Comment: @andrew: The edit was providing exemplary code what is meant. There is  not much reason if someone posts hard-to-decipher code in a question to keep it especially as it contains errors because of while creating such hard to read code, shooting in the own foot is on the agenda.

Comment: @andrew: Also there is no correct answer, it's just a mistake the OP did, this on this very bare level does not qualify as a programming question. See the linked duplicate that actually asks.

Comment: ok, I actually commented before it was marked as a dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && isset($_GET['user_id']) && isset($_GET['comment']))  
   $post_id = $_GET['post_id'] && 
   $user_id = $_GET['user_id'] && 
   $comment = $_GET['comment'];
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && isset($_GET['user_id']) && isset($_GET['comment'])) {
   $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
   $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
   $comment = $_GET['comment'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php file try like this

```
if($_GET['post_id'] && $_GET['user_id'] && $_GET['comment']) {
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];
//your stuff
}
```